# NewForm.aspx customization. Change width of current input and insert it to table column

Tags: custom-form

I'm trying to change SharePoint form according this template:

[image]

So I changed colspan to 2: , and inserted inside  another table with 3 columns:
                        
                        
                            
                                Please Note Reason for change
                            
                        
                        
                            
                            
                        
                    
                    
                        
                            
                                
                                    
                                        
                                            My Person:
                                        
                                    
                                    
                                        
                                            My Current Route:
                                        
                                    
                                    
                                        
                                            My New Route:

```
                <tr >
                    <td valign="top" class="ms-formlabel" colspan="2">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="197px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                                    <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff5{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="SalesPerson" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff5',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@SalesPerson')}"/>
                                    <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff5description{$Pos}" FieldName="SalesPerson" ControlMode="New"/>
                                </td>
                                <td width="197px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel" >
                                    <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff6{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="CurrentRoute" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff6',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@CurrentRoute')}"/>
                                    <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff6description{$Pos}" FieldName="CurrentRoute" ControlMode="New"/>
                                </td>
                                <td width="197px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                                    <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff7{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="NewRoute" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff7',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@NewRoute')}"/>
                                    <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff7description{$Pos}" FieldName="NewRoute" ControlMode="New"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel" colspan="2">
                        <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                            <hr /><nobr><b>OPTIONAL:</b></nobr></H3>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

whole code I pasted here: [source](https://gist.github.com/Gennady-G/7179c94e4a19baeeb895ed9beef42c8f#file-gistfile1-txt)

But I cannot modify in SharePoint:FormField width(it should be smaller). As I understand from IE dev tools I can change .ms-long style, but it changes all inputs on pages and I don't know how to apply it in SharePoint Designer to only few:

[image]

For better understanding I can attach picture of table that I want to get as a result:
[image]

Comment: You could try 3 separate tables

Comment: Thank You for answer! 3 tables unfortunately does not help. But I resolved adding .ms-long{width:95%;} style. https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Gennady-G/91f045816068d9a38f1133135dc94bae/raw/271eb9012497b57f667b26858e0e7796625803e9/gistfile1.txt